# how to know if an optimization problem has a closed form solution?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have this optimization problem which is linear and therefore convex.  how should I calculate the closed form solution:

$\min_{\eta_i} \max_i \frac{\eta_i+\beta_i}{R_i}$ s.t.  $\sum \eta_i=\alpha$ and $\eta_i \geq 0$

where $\beta_i$'s and $R_i$'s are all positive.

so I wrote it as the linear form of

$\min_{\eta_i} K$ s.t. $K\geq \frac{\eta_i+\beta_i}{R_i}$ and $\eta_i \geq 0$

which indicates a linear programming. How should I find the closed form solution.

Comment: It would help to know properties of the parameters, such as if all $R_i$ are positive or not. Nevertheless you can guess a solution where equality holds everywhere and then, in many cases, prove optimality of that.

Comment: Here is an example of what kind of thing can go wrong: If $R_1=1, R_2=-1,\alpha=0$ then the infimum is $-\infty$.

Comment: $R_i$'s are all positive actually.

Comment: so I guessed a solution by putting  all  inqualities $K≥ηiRi$ at binding  and getting $\eta_i=\frac{\alpha+\sum \beta_i}{\sum R_i}R_i-\beta_i$ but then other constraints of $\eta_i \geq 0 $ don't necassarily hold...

Comment: What is $\beta_i$? Introduction of such new variables was unexpected.

Comment: sorry let me  correct the post .  the original optimization problem is now written